# How to WebFluxTest whit ReactiveSecurityContexHolder

Tags: spring-security, okhttp, spring-webflux, spring-test

Here a simple Class reading the Principal user from the spring security context:

```
public Mono<Void> getAndCheckAccessRights(Integer agencyKey) {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(securityContext -> getAccessRights(agencyKey, securityContext.getAuthentication().getName()))
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                log.error("No security context found!");
                throw new AuthorizationException("No security context found!");
            }))
            .flatMap(accessRightsDtoMono -> checkAccessRights(accessRightsDtoMono))
            .then();
}

private Mono<AccessRightsDto> getAccessRights(Integer agencyKey, String bensl) {
    return dataServiceWebClient.get()
            .uri("/access_rights/" + agencyKey + "/" + bensl)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(AccessRightsDto.class)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                log.error("No user found!");
                throw new AuthorizationException("No user found!");
            }));
}
```

While testing it does not what it is supposed to do, execution just jump code lines over without executing method streams in .map or .flatMap, 
Logs are not printed and there is no debug logging on any level, test just runs as everithing is terminated correctly, i dont have any clue whatsovewer why this happen:

```
@WebFluxTest(AccessRightService.class)
...
@Test
@WithMockUser
void getAndCheckAccessRights_NOT_AUTHORIZED() throws JsonProcessingException {
    AccessRightsDto testAccessRightsDto = AccessRightsDto
            .builder(123456789, "test", "test", PUBLISH, PUBLISH, PUBLISH, PUBLISH, PUBLISH,
                    PUBLISH, PUBLISH, PUBLISH, NO_ACCESS)
            .build();
    MockResponse response = new MockResponse();
    response.setResponseCode(HttpStatus.OK.value()).setBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testAccessRightsDto));
    mockWebServer.enqueue(response);
    assertThrows(AuthorizationException.class, () -> accessRightService.getAndCheckAccessRights(123456789));
}
```

Off course when running the application it just work correctly as expected, testing is strange!

App running with spring boot 2.2.2 and okhttp3 mockwebserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I forgot to put`.block()` after `getAndCheckAccessRights` which propagate the input of getting the object, whitout that nothing will happen.

It is actually not that clear how does it works in case of Netty, because it does not accept `.block()`'s but on tests is ok to call it.